# Have page background scroll with the user

Tags: html, css, background

I'm having trouble getting the background to scroll with a user. I'd like 12% of the top to be white and 6% of the bottom to be white and the rest the screen to be blue. I'd like the white at the top to only display when the user is at the top of the page and the white at the bottom to display when the user is at the bottom of the page.

[Here's an image of the page, zoom in to fit your screen then scroll so you get the idea of what I'm going for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umtri.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <body>
<div id="bg-top"></div>
</body>
<style>

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: scrolling;
}
#bg-top {
  background-color: #00b9ff;
  position: scrolling;
  top: 12%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 6%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}


</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use position **absolute** instead of **fixed** like this :

*I put a big value on the height of body to see the result better*

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  min-height:1000px;
}

#bg-top {
  background-color: #00b9ff;
  top: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg-top"></div>
```

Comment: That worked but there's a slight white border on each side of the page, would you know how to get rid of this?

Comment: @HTMLHelp yes simply add `margin:0` to body, am gonna update my answer ;)

Comment: Amazing, Thank You!

Comment: @HTMLHelp you may mark the answer as accpeted to close the question :)